# Do I need to install Network Manager for Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 64 LiveUSB

Tags: usb, network-manager, deb, usb-modem, modem

I have Alcatel Speedtouch ADLS USB modem and I have been trying to figure out how to set it up. I finally found a page explaining it simply. But the Network Manager program link doesn't work. I think I saw this program already installed on Ubuntu?

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=797804 (from year 2008)

And I would like to ask how to install `.deb` files?

(As far I learned I will try to copy them in a folder in my flashdisk and then I will run terminal in Ubuntu and then I will write this code for every file.)

```
cd /home/ctest/Downloads/
dpkg -i random_name.deb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understood how to properly setup packages, but you also need the dependencies of the packages.

In this page you can find packages `.deb` and dependencies of packages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Download them and install.